# Complex number with z to the power of 4

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

I have to find all $z\in C$ for which **BOTH** of the following is true:

1) $|z|=1$

2) $|z^4+1| = 1$

I understand that the 1) is a unit circle, but I can't find out what would be the 2). 
Calculating the power of $(x+yi)$ seems wrong because I get a function with square root of polynomial of the 8th degree.

I've even tried to equate the two, since their modulo is the same, like this:

$|z|= |z^4+1|$

and then separating two possibilities in which the equation holds, but I get only

$z^4\pm z+1=0$

which I don't know how to calculate.

I guess there is an elegant solution which I am unable to see...

Any help?

Comment: Use the fact that $\lvert z\rvert = 1 \Rightarrow \lvert z^4\rvert = 1$, and that $\{w : \lvert w+1\rvert = 1\}$ is the circle with radius $1$ around $-1$.

Comment: Try solving quartic equiation using Ferrari's method

Comment: I hope that you have realized that the complex absolute value does NOT work like:
$$|z_1|=|z_2|\Longleftrightarrow z_1=\pm z_2.$$ You seemed to be aware of this in part 1, but your attempt at part 2 (or where they simultaneous equations?) shows that there may be some misconceptions remaining...

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out later. I thought it works like that, but obviously not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems helpful to square both sides. From the second equation, you get $$1 = (z^4 + 1)(\overline{z}^4 + 1) = (z \overline{z})^4 + z^4 + \overline{z}^4 + 1 = z^4 + \overline{z}^4 + 2.$$ That is, $z^4 + \overline{z^4} = -1.$

The first equation lets you write $z = e^{i \theta}$, so you have $$-1 = e^{4i\theta} + e^{-4i \theta} = 2\cos(4\theta);$$ in other words, $\cos(4\theta) = \frac{-1}{2}.$ The solutions of this are well-known.

Comment: Are you assuming both equations 1) and 2) to hold? I got the impression that there were two separate exercises here.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, I am trying to find $z$ such that both equations hold at once. I got the impression that this is what is being asked, since the OP has tried to set $|z| = |z^4 + 1|$

Comment: Hmm. I guess that's possible, may be even likely. I rather got the impression that the OP was not sure ...

Comment: I am sorry for not writing the question more clearly. Cocopuffs was right, both equations should hold. I've updated the Q.

Answer (score 2):

Use polar coordinates to do part 2.

Setting $z=re^{i\phi}$ gives $z^4=r^4e^{i4\phi}.$ Therefore
$$
z^4+1=(r^4\cos4\phi+1)+ir^4\sin4\phi,
$$
and thus
$$
|z^4+1|=1\Leftrightarrow (r^4\cos4\phi+1)^2+(r^4\sin4\phi)^2=1.
$$
Expanding the terms on the l.h.s. of the last equation shows that the equation holds, iff
$$
(r=0)\qquad \text{or}\qquad r^4+2\cos4\phi=0.
$$
Therefore in polar form we get (in addition to the origin) the curve
$$
r=\root 4\of{-2\cos4\phi}.
$$
For the r.h.s. to be defined we need $\cos4\phi\le0$, so there will be something only in the sectors $\arg z\in[\pi/8,3\pi/8]$ and three other sectors gotten by rotating this with an integer multiple of $\pi/2$.

Below you see a Mathematica plot. The maximum modulus of $z$ is obviously $\root 4\of 2$, achieved at the points $z=\root 4\of 2e^{i(2k+1)\pi/4}$, $k=0,1,2,3,$ where we have $z^4=-2$.

[image]

Comment: As you can see Mathematica has difficulties near the origin here. This is because the fourth root goes to zero very steeply, and apparently the division points didn't hit the odd multiples of $\pi/8$ exactly. I guess I could tune it up by selecting an appropriate value for `PlotPoints`, but this picture will probably serve well enough.

Comment: I assumed that there were two exercises: part 1 using the first equation only, and part 2 using the second equation only. If you really were asked to find the points, where both equations hold simultaneously, then Cocopuffs' answer is the way to go. Please clarify.

Comment: Both equations must hold simultaneously. I am sorry for not specifying the problem better. I have updated my question. However, I am glad you misassumed the problem, because I managed to extend my knowledge of $C$ a lot through your explanation. Thanks.